# /* in unix echo command outputs some default path with string

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to echo an user input from parameter.
When the user enters any string having /* character it prints with some default bin boot path.
I dont want to print it.

Please note the user input is dynamic as given below,.

```
$ b="/* abc"  #User input ; it can be anything like, "bcd /* abc" or without /* too    
$ echo $b
/1 /bin /boot /db_dyn /dev /etc /srv /sys /tmp /tools /usr /var /x abc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good practice to quote variables when `echo`ing. In this case, it would give you the desired output:

```
$ b="/* abc"
$ echo "$b"
/* abc
```

Note that if you don't quote, the actual echo is:

```
echo /* abc
```

So `*` gets expanded and matches all the items in `/`, and then prints `abc`.

The same would happen if you had the `?` char, which would be expanded to all the items having one char.

Comment: If I use double quotes, the lines are printing one by one. the user input is coming from file. say b=`'cat abc.txt'` this abc.txt contains multiple lines; if i dont use double quotes in echo, it will print in single line. i want in that manner. Not it prints all lines as it is in the file

Comment: @logan as I always tell you, try to give some relevant sample input data and completed desired output. What you are commenting now is pretty different from the original question.

Comment: I understand., shall i raise a new question, will it not be a duplicate ?

Comment: No problem, we can comment it here. If we don't get there, then you can raise a new question. What if you do this? `paste -s <<< "$b"` or `echo "$b" | tr '\n' ' '`. In both cases, the `$b` variable will be printed in one single line.